# JS Regex lookbehind not working in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, regex-lookarounds

I have this following regex which is working in chrome but causes an error in firefox or safari. I need to modify it to make it work. Can anybody help out a poor soul? Thanks in advance!

regex: `/(?=<tag>)(.*?)(?<=<\/tag>)/`

Basically, I have to match any char in between `<tag>` and `</tag>` and need to retain both tags. I used this expression as an argument to array.split.

**input:** `"The quick brown <tag>fox</tag> jumps over the lazy <tag>dog</tag>"`

**operation:** input.split(regex)

**output:** `["The quick brown ", "<tag>fox</tag>", " jumps over the lazy ", "<tag>dog</tag>"]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>Firefox and</s> <sup>[*Has*](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)</sup>
Safari doesn't have support for lookbehind yet, you can use capture group ( used so that this the pattern on which we are splitting will be also be added in output ) and split on `<tag>  </tag>`

```js
let str = "The quick brown <tag>fox</tag> jumps over the lazy <tag>dog</tag>"

let regex = /(<tag>.*?<\/tag>)/

console.log(str.split(regex).filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: It works. I appreciate the response. I realized I over engineered my initial regex. Cheers

Comment: No need using `g` modifier in this case since it is the default behavior of `split`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
<tag>.*?<\/tag>|[^<>]+
```

would work OK:

#### Test

```js
function regularExpression(regex, str) {
 let m, arr = [];
 while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
   regex.lastIndex++;
  }


  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
   arr.push(match.trim());
   console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
 }
 return arr;
}

const expression = /<tag>.*?<\/tag>|[^<>]+/g;
const string = 'The quick brown <tag>fox</tag> jumps over the lazy <tag>dog</tag>';

console.log(regularExpression(expression, string));
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pEe5Df/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/pEe5Df/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it works but I feel the first answer is simpler and enough for the implementation requirements. Thanks for providing visualization!