# Is there any alternate for Positive lookbehind regex for safari browser?

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, positive-lookbehind

this regex **/(?<=.+)(\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n){1,}/g** works for major browser but is breaking on safari. Is there any alternate for the same?

Comment: may be this will help you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460501/js-regex-lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox-and-safari

Comment: `(?<=.+)` = `(?<=.)` = `(?!^)`

Comment: If you need to replace, eg. [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) like this: [`(.)[\r\n]+` and replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/neDPyJ/1) if you need to extract the *crlf* part: [`.([\r\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/BlgoJp/1) - and if you just need to match, even [`.[\r\n]`](https://regex101.com/r/KGCoIS/1) could suffice. It's essential to know about the context, the regex is used.